# Replace missing value with average of that month

Tags: r, data-extraction

I've data of occupancy at a daily level, there are some null(NA) values in Occupancy Percentage.

I want to replace the occupancy percentage of that respective month for that respective ID.

I would be explaining with a sample data(mocked-up data):

```
Date       ID   Occupancy%
1/2/2018    1   95
2/2/2018    1   94
3/2/2018    1   94
4/2/2018    1   96
5/2/2018    1   94
6/2/2018    1   NA
7/2/2018    1   96
8/2/2018    1   94
1/2/2018    2   75
2/2/2018    2   NA
3/2/2018    2   79
4/2/2018    2   82
5/2/2018    2   NA
6/2/2018    2   76
7/2/2018    2   78
8/2/2018    2   80
```

I want to replace the NA's with average of that month and with respect to its ID.

I want the outcome to be

1. `6/2/2018   1   NA` should be  `6/2/2018    1   94.7`
2. `1/2/2018   2   NA` should be  `1/2/2018    2   78.3`
3. `5/2/2018   2   NA` should be  `5/2/2018    2   78.3`

Any suggestions on how to achieve this in r?

Or is it easy to perform in SQL, if so how can it be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=with(dat,ave(Occupancy.,sub(".*?\\/","",Date),ID,FUN=function(x)mean(x,na.rm=T)))
> transform(dat,b=replace(x<-Occupancy.,y<-is.na(x),a[y]))
       Date ID Occupancy.        b
1  1/2/2018  1         95 95.00000
2  2/2/2018  1         94 94.00000
3  3/2/2018  1         94 94.00000
4  4/2/2018  1         96 96.00000
5  5/2/2018  1         94 94.00000
6  6/2/2018  1         NA 94.71429
7  7/2/2018  1         96 96.00000
8  8/2/2018  1         94 94.00000
9  1/2/2018  2         75 75.00000
10 2/2/2018  2         NA 78.33333
11 3/2/2018  2         79 79.00000
12 4/2/2018  2         82 82.00000
13 5/2/2018  2         NA 78.33333
14 6/2/2018  2         76 76.00000
15 7/2/2018  2         78 78.00000
16 8/2/2018  2         80 80.00000
```